# How to invoke a template operator[] in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a map that allows std::any as values, then I return the std::any object.

I would like to save some characters in my code. so I have

```
class MyMap {
    std::map<std::string, std::any> map;

public:
    template<typename T>
    const T & operator[](const std::string & name) const {
        auto & aux = map[name];

        return std::any_cast<T&>(aux);
    }
}
```

so, instead of

```
auto foo = std::any_cast<int>(myMap["key"]);
```

I would like to

```
auto foo = myMap<int>["key"]; // or something like this, beacuse, the compiler tells this syntax is incorrect
```

I don't know if this is even possible, and if is, how do I have to invoke the operator[]?

Comment: You can't, unless you call the `operator[]()` explicitly.   For example, `auto foo = myMap.operator[]<int>("key")`.    That sort of defeats the point of having an `operator[]` though, since you can't do `myMap["key"]`.    Better to use a member function directly so you can do (say) `myMap.get<int>("key")`

Comment: `myMap[SomeTag<int>("key")]` would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* invoke this as:

```cpp
auto foo = mymap.operator[]<int>("key");
```

...but if you're going to do that, you'd be a lot better off making it a normal member function:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    const T & get(const std::string & name) const {
        auto aux = map[name];

        return std::any_cast<T&>(aux);
    }
```

...so calling it would be something like `auto foo = mymap.get<int>("key");`

The other obvious possibility would to pass a reference to the destination, so the type can be inferred. You can't do that with `operator[]` (which only accepts one argument), but you can with `operator()` (which accepts an arbitrary number of arguments):

```cpp
template <typename T>
void operator()(std::string const &name, T &dest) { 
    dest = std::any_cast<T>(map[name]);
}

int foo;
mymap("key", foo);
```

I think I prefer the `get` version though.